# Animated kids' cartoon about a boy from Earth and a team of other aliens and beings saving space

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, space

I remember it was similar to a CGI-animated movie/series (definitely not drawn), maybe a miniseries, but it involved a boy from Earth, probably a teenager, who was able to travel to space and meet up with a team of other aliens and beings.

At the beginning, he was at like a playground which had a roundabout/merry-go-around. His suit was similar to an astronaut's and was white with green trimming; he either had blond or red/ginger hair.

The team was in charge of helping to protect the solar system and the main "rulers" were three floating "beings" whose heads resembled clouded black crystal orbs and they wore capes; one wore white, another wore red, and the third was either green or blue. I believe the red one turned out to be evil and was plotting to destroy a planet. Long story short, the team wins and the villain is punished by his fellow leaders.

One other thing I remember is that one hero rode like a ring-shaped vehicle/spaceship and his character was blue. There was a female heroine that I believe was a magenta color (not entirely sure about that one).

Not sure if this'll help, but I watched it from a CD. It was one of those CDs that had two different episodes from two different series or movies. I remember that you could pick left or right and the other choice had something to do with trains, but it wasn't from *Thomas the Tank Engine* or similar to Thomas. However, I do also believe the train tunnels were just to "take you" to start the episode or movie. I'm not very sure either, since it's been 10+ years since I've last seen the animation.

It is not *Escape from Planet Earth* (2013) or *Planet 51* (2009).

Comment: Hi. In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: somwhere around 2008-2010, I think it was made before that though,

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[Planet Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Heroes#Comic_book/DVD)***...?

Judging by the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Heroes#Comic_book/DVD), this was mainly a toy line released by Fisher-Price in 2009, but three CGI-animated episodes were released on DVD.

> Three DVD episodes and comic books have been released for the Planet Heroes. The DVD episodes are approx. 16 minutes.
>
> - Comic/DVD #1 Ace in Space
> - Comic/DVD #2 The Ace that Jumped Over the Moon
> - Comic/DVD #3 Here Comes the Sun

According to [TheTVDB](https://thetvdb.com/series/planet-heroes/allseasons/official), there's also a fourth episode titled "Slingshot."

The 'Planet Heroes' themselves are a team of nine heroes that defend Earth's solar system. Each member is from one of the nine planets in the system (or eight-and-a-half planets, as they put it at one point, in reference to Pluto).

The main protagonist, Earth's representative, is a brown-haired boy called Ace. When on Earth, he wears normal clothes but he has a special watch that alerts him when he's needed by the Planet Heroes, and he can press a button on the watch that causes his clothes to transform into a mostly white astronaut-style suit with green and blue trim. His skateboard also reconfigures into a rocket-propelled platform which he uses to fly to a space station past the Sun, where the Planet Heroes meet up.

> [image: Image of Ace, from "Planet Heroes."]

Saturn's representative is a mostly teal-coloured alien called Rings, who rides in in a flying contraption that resembles a giant gold wedding band.

> [image: Image of Rings, from "Planet Heroes."]

The only female on the team seems to be Venus' representative, Dazzle, but her colour scheme is mainly yellow and orange, rather than magenta. Aside from Ace, she's the most human-looking member of the team.

Judging by the episode, "Slingshot," the Planet Heroes receive their mission orders from two beings wearing gown-like outfits with orbs on their heads, one being mostly blue and the other, mostly green.

> [image: Image of the Solar Panel, from "Planet Heroes."]

The main antagonist is a guy called Black Hole, also known as Professor Darkness, who wants to destroy the solar system and looks like the last two characters I just described, except that his outfit is mostly red.

> [image: Image of Black Hole, from "Planet Heroes."]

"Slingshot" also begins with a scene where Ace is on Earth, racing another kid on skateboards through a children's playground. At one point, Ace grabs hold of a playground spinner and swings around it to build up momentum, so that could be the episode you remember watching.

The scene in question begins at around the 1:38 mark in the video below.

Comment: OMGGGGG YESSS IT IS EXACTLY THIS. Thank you soooo much, it's been killing me trying to figure it out and nothing was showing up, my life saver!

Comment: @CBA - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the grey check mark near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.